# Convert a factor into binary dummies but not all factors present

Tags: r, one-hot-encoding

I have a number of data frames that contain a factor that I wish to expand out into a number of binary equivalents (one hot encoding). However, in each data frame not all the possible factors are present, but I do know what all the possible factors are (there are 70 such factors). I want to add all the possible binary dummies to every data frame.

From the code below, I can create the dummies within each data frame, but not all the possible dummies. For example, set1.df does not have any person in category "E" or "F", whilst set2.df does not have anyone in category "D".   What's needed is additional columns set1.dfE set1.dfF in set1.df that are all 0, and column set2.dfD in set2.df that is all zeros. I can not rbind set1.df and set2.df before creating the dummies because I need to do some processing of each data frame using the binary variables before rbinding. Just to re-iterate I know what levels are possible in my data before hand, eg "A" to "F".

```
library(dummies)

person_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
person_cat <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","D","A","A","A")
set1.df <- data.frame(person_id,person_cat)

person_id <- c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
person_cat <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","E","E","F","A")
set2.df <- data.frame(person_id,person_cat)

dummies1 <- dummy(set1.df[,2])
dummies2 <- dummy(set2.df[,2])

dummies1
dummies2
```

The expected output is:

```
> dummies1
      set1.dfA set1.dfB set1.dfC set1.dfD set1.dfE set1.dfF
 [1,]        1        0        0        0        0        0
 [2,]        0        1        0        0        0        0
 [3,]        0        0        1        0        0        0
 [4,]        1        0        0        0        0        0
 [5,]        0        1        0        0        0        0
 [6,]        0        0        1        0        0        0
 [7,]        0        0        0        1        0        0
 [8,]        1        0        0        0        0        0
 [9,]        1        0        0        0        0        0
[10,]        1        0        0        0        0        0
> dummies2
      set2.dfA set2.dfB set2.dfC set2.df$D set2.dfE set2.dfF
 [1,]        1        0        0        0        0        0
 [2,]        0        1        0        0        0        0
 [3,]        0        0        1        0        0        0
 [4,]        1        0        0        0        0        0
 [5,]        0        1        0        0        0        0
 [6,]        0        0        1        0        0        0
 [7,]        0        0        0        0        1        0
 [8,]        0        0        0        0        1        0
 [9,]        0        0        0        0        0        1
[10,]        1        0        0        0        0        0
```

Comment: Define the variables using `factor()` and use the `levels = ` argument to add all necessary levels.

Comment: `I can not rbind set1.df and set2.df before creating the dummies because I need to do some processing of each data frame using the binary variables before rbinding` I believe this statement might be challenged. You might want to get acquainted with `dplyr::group_by` used with `dplyr::mutate` for instance.

Comment: I added lines of the form: `person_cat<-factor(person_cat,levels=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))` and whilst the data frames do now have 6 levels, "dummy" ignores the unused levels. The addition of a `drop=FALSE` option to "dummy" fixes this and creates the necessary variables. Thanks.

Comment: You could write an answer to your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 library(dummies)

person_id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
person_cat <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","D","A","A","A")
person_cat < -factor(person_cat,levels=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
set1.df <- data.frame(person_id,person_cat)

person_id <- c(11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)
person_cat <- c("A","B","C","A","B","C","E","E","F","A")
person_cat <- factor(person_cat,levels=c("A","B","C","D","E","F"))
set2.df <- data.frame(person_id,person_cat)

dummies1 <- dummy(set1.df[,2],drop=FALSE)
dummies2 <- dummy(set2.df[,2],drop=FALSE)

dummies1
dummies2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
levels <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')

data <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(person_id), ncol = length(levels)))
names(data) <- levels 
for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  for (j in 1:length(data)){
    data[i, j] <- ifelse(set1.df[i, 2] == names(data)[j], 1, 0)
  }
}
```

You should create a empty dataframe with the same number of rows as IDs and as many columns as levels you have in set1.df. Then, using a loop you evaluates the person_cat in every column. Only when person_cat is equal to the column name (category_level) the value of the cell will be 1.